# Can I test a responsive website in Android Studio? How?

Tags: android, testing, responsive-design, web

I am trying to test a website responsiveness to see if it works fine on Android devices, but I don't have an Android device. Is there a way to test website responsiveness on Android Studio? I have already tried resizing windows and all those websites that do that. What I want is a software that emulates the Android operating system. If yes, please share how. Thank you.

Comment: Is it somewhat related to webView ?

Comment: How about Chrome device mode https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/device-mode

Comment: Why was this downvoted? It's a normal question to ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open a Chrome Browser -Right mouse click and select Inspect Element. 
To the right of the tab Elements is a picture of a phone. Click That. Then you will see the browser resized.
Go to the top drop down menus on top to get some awesome choices.
Select one of the options from the Device drop down. 
Then select one of the options from Network drop down.
Reload the page while doing a speed test from the far right tab. 
Then you have a single user analysis of your app. For multi-user tests use JMeter.

Comment: Thanks for all responses. All answers are different solutions to size of the browser i need to somehow run the website on an andriod platform. Its bc the web works fine on iphone and tablets but good on andriod so i need to test specifically on andriod platform. Its internet browser.

Comment: It doesn't make it Android.

Comment: this works somewhat, but really isn't the best answer.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, you can test a responsive website using Android Studio's emulator. Here are the steps to do this:

1. Download and install Android Studio - https://developer.android.com/studio/
2. Launch ADV Manager (Android Virtual Device Manager) within Android Studio and create a new virtual device
3. Click the play button to launch your app. Choose the device that you created in ADV
4. When the emulator opens, close the app that opens on the emulator and navigate to the web browser on the device. You should be able to test your website without issue now.

If you run into problems, make sure that you have all updates installed in Android Studio.

Here is a reference that you can use to get the emulator up and running: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator

Comment: this should be the accepted answer, as using chrome to "simulate" android doesn't quite do the trick for testing responsiveness issues that show up on a real android device